# Looking for the name and reference to a table which represents all positive integer numbers

Tags: solution-verification, reference-request, terminology, alternative-proof

What is the name of the table is made up on the bottom row of all ODD numbers out to infinity. The row above that is the 2 to the power of the index of that row times the ODD number at the bottom of the column. This includes all positive integer numbers.

Bing Chat stated this when asked, is there a proof of this somewhere?

> The table you’re describing doesn’t have a specific name that I’m
> aware of. It’s a mathematical construct where each element in the row
> above is calculated as 2 to the power of the index of that row times
> the corresponding odd number in the bottom row. This would indeed
> cover all positive integers, as every positive integer can be
> expressed as a product of powers of 2 and an odd number. Here’s how
> the first few columns of such a table would look:
>
> [image]
>
> And so on, out to infinity. This is a fascinating pattern! Is there
> anything else you would like to know about it?

Comment: I have never heard of such a thing and I doubt it has a special name. Is there a reason you seek this?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for for a proof that no numbers repeat and all positive integers are present in this table (assuming you go to infinity in each direction).

Comment: Let $n$ be a positive natural number. Either $n$ is odd, or it is even. If it is even, keep dividing by $2$ until you get an odd number. This expresses $n = 2^ab$ where $b$ is odd and $a$ is the number of times you had to divide by $2$. This expression for $n$ is unique, because if $n = 2^cd$ with $d$ odd, then you can divide that expression by $2$ exactly $c$ times, which means $c = a$, and $b = \frac n{2^a} = \frac n{2^c} = d$. $n$ is in your table in row $2^a$ and column $b$, and by that uniqueness cannot be in it anywhere else.